# How to create Hidden Field in table dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create hidden field to put id in it and i have never done that before...

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetCountries',
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'Json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
               var $data = $('<table id="mytable" class="t"> </table>').addClass('table table-responsive table-striped');
                var header = "<thead><tr><th>Country ID</th><th>Country</th></tr></thead>";


                $.each(data, function (i, row) {
                    var $row = $('<tr/>');
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(row.CountryId))
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(row.CountryName));
                    $hidden = $(' <input type="hidden" name="hid" value=""' + row.CountryId + '">');
                    $row.append($hidden);
```

and please tell me how to get id from the hidden field something like this:

```
   $(document).on("click", '.editbtn', function () {
                var associateID = $(this).parents("tr").find('td').find(":input").val();
                alert(associateID);
});
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of `<input name='hid'>` by using the selector `$('input[name="hid"]').val()`. However, it seems that you have an `.editBtn` in every row, so you can try using the selector

```
  var associateID = $(this).parents('tr').find('input[name="hid"]').val();
```

I noticed there's an extra `"` after the assignment of `value`, there should only be one, e.g.

```
  $hidden = $(' <input type="hidden" name="hid" value="' + row.CountryId + '">');
```